# wamp server seeing folder in all network

Tags: cmd.exe, wamp, public-folders

I have installed magento on my localhost my colleagues can see the local host page which is wampserver and all informations of wamp server homepage but they cannot go further and see magento2 folder which I created in C:\wamp\www so I went to permissions and here it is:

[image]

I don't know if it is from permissions or it relates to other thing.any help would be appreciated

Comment: actually i solved my problem by changing the localhost to my computer full name

Comment: I will answer it, maybe it will help someone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when installing magento, or some other application instead of having localhost you should use ip or full computer name